# How to sort descending using foreach on php?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I wanted to sort the feed from new post to older post.
This code is posting the older feed on top while newer feed on the bottom

```
@if(count($feeds) > 0)
    @foreach($feeds->all() as $feed)
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <blockquote>
                <p>{{ $feed->feed }}</p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

This is in the `controller` to call the feeds

```
public function home() {
    $feeds = Feed::all();
    return view('home', ['feeds' => $feeds]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) like so:

```
use DB;
...

$feeds = DB::table('your_table_name')
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
          ->get();
```

you can also do:

```
$feeds = Feed::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

and if you don't have the `created_at` you can just use the `id` column.